# Determine the number of columns that do not contain a single letter 'K' in a three-dimensional array of characters

Tags: c++

**I have a task I cannot figure out how to solve. The problem is:**

- Form an array of type char with a size of 2x3x4 elements.
- Initialize it with random characters from A to Z.
- Determine the number of columns that do not contain a single letter 'K' (total columns 2 * 4).
- Use pointers.

I started, but I don’t know how to count the number of columns that do not contain the letter K.

```
const int N = 2, M = 3, K = 4;
char a[N][M][K];
char *pa = &a[0][0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
            *pa = 'A' + rand() % 26;
            cout << *(pa++) << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, at least in my opinion, this is a bit too broad of a question, but I'm not a mod so I'll just stick to answering:

```
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) { // checks every column
        bool hasK = false;    //--
        for(char k: a[i][j]) {// |
            if(k == 'k') {    // |
                hasK = true;  // |_checks if the column
                break;        // | contains the char 'k'
            }                 // |
        }                     // |
        if(!hasK) count++;    //--
    }
}
```